# Autohotkey: Splitting a concatenated string into string and number

Tags: autohotkey

I am using an input box to request a string from the user that has the form "sometext5". I would like to separate this via regexp into a variable for the string component and a variable for the number. The number then shall be used in a loop.

The following just returns "0", even when I enter a string in the form "itemize5"

```
!n::
InputBox, UserEnv, Environment, Please enter an environment!, , 240, 120
If ErrorLevel
    return
Else
    FoundPos := RegExMatch(%UserEnv%, "\d+$")
    MsgBox %FoundPos%
retur
```

n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `FoundPos`, as its name implies, contains the position of the leftmost occurrence of the needle. It does **not** contain anything you specifically want to match with your regex.
2. When passing variable contents to a function, don't enclose the variable names in percent signs (like `%UserEnv%`).
3. Your regex `\d+$` will only match numbers at the end of the string, not the text before it.

A possible solution:

```
myText := "sometext55"
if( RegExMatch(myText, "(.*?)(\d+)$", splitted) ) {
    msgbox, Text: %splitted1%`nNumber: %splitted2%
}
```

As described in the [docs](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm), `splitted` will be set to a pseudo-array (`splitted1`, `splitted2` ...), with each element containing the matched subpattern of your regex (the stuff that is in between round brackets).

Comment: 2. was the hint I needed. Finally I managed to finish the whole script: http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=2763